# Entity Framework custom HistoryContext causes migrations table to be recreated and fail

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6

I am using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` provider and `Entity Framework 6.2.0`.

My current task - is to get rid of EF default behavior to prepend `dbo.` schema name in front of all database entities (command: `update-database -StartupProject MyDbProject -Verbose -Script`).

> create table "dbo"."MyEntity"
>
> create table "dbo"."__MigrationHistory"

This behavior causes issues when running SQL scripts from within custom schema in `Oracle DB`.

In my main db context I set the following (**irrelevant code is omitted**):

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{

    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("ApplicationDbContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntity { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(String.Empty);
    }
}
```

This action allowed me to clean-up some of the "dbo" schema names in front of table and index creation scripts.

> create table "MyEntity"
>
> create table "dbo"."__MigrationHistory"

However, there was still one place, that was not affected by the change - that is "__MigrationHistory" table, which apparently uses it's own context. To remove "dbo" for this table - I used following approach:

```
public class CustomHistoryContext : HistoryContext
{
    public CustomHistoryContext(DbConnection dbConnection, string defaultSchema)
        : base(dbConnection, defaultSchema)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(String.Empty);
    }
}

public class CustomHistoryConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public CustomHistoryConfiguration()
    {
        this.SetHistoryContext("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client",
            (connection, defaultSchema) => new CustomHistoryContext(connection, String.Empty));
    }
}
```

> create table "MyEntity"
>
> create table "__MigrationHistory"

Both of these changes combined - allows to run the migration successfully the first time (command: `update-database -StartupProject MyDbProject -Verbose`).

However, I have encountered an issue, that upon second run - `_MigrationHistory` is being **dropped** for no apparent reason and the EF attempts to migrate all tables anew. Since there is already existent tables (such as `MyEntity`) - it fails.

> ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

What causes `_MigrationHistory` to be dropped upon new migration attempt? The expected behavior, is that EF determines that migration was already run and outputs in the console that there are no new migrations to be run!